# Java jTable color row on defined cell change

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Hi all I am not finding what's incorrect about my code below. It populates the table and headers just fine. However, when I change *row 1, colum 1* to **test** and click off it does not color the row like I was expecting. Then clicking off the one I clicked on turns green and anywhere I click on the table from then on just changes green.

The column won't change from **1 (Company)** as that will be the default column which changes will be made. The **row** is the only dynamic number here.

The flow to test:

- double-click IBM.
- type in **test**.
- click on any another cell in order to save that cell value.
- the row does not change (row 1).
- click on the test cell again.
- all rows will change to the green color.

The Expected flow:

- double-click IBM.
- type in **test**.
- click on any another cell in order to save that cell value.
- the cell that was changed to **test** changes that row **green**.
- click on **Shares** for cell **(3, 3)**.
- double-click and change **4000** to *1000*.
- click on any another cell in order to save that cell value.
- the cell that was changed to **1000** changes that row **red**.

Populated the table and headers:

[image]

Clicking and changing the *row 1, column 1* value to **test**:

[image]

Clicking off that cell onto another one after edit:

[image]

And now, click on any other cell (notice the test row is not green as it should be):

[image]

Now clicking on the cell I edited to **test**:

[image]

And you see above it's just coloring each row I click on regardless of the logic I said

**if ("test".equals(type)) {...**.

The java code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TableRowRenderingTip extends JPanel {
    public TableRowRenderingTip() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price", "Boolean"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.5), Boolean.TRUE},
            {"Sell", "Dell", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25), Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Short Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35), Boolean.TRUE},
            {"Buy", "MicroSoft", new Integer(4000), new Double(27.50), Boolean.FALSE},
            {"Short Sell", "Cisco", new Integer(5000), new Double(20), Boolean.TRUE}
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(1, column).getClass();
            }
        };

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Border", createBorder(model));
        add(tabbedPane);
    }

    private JComponent createBorder(DefaultTableModel model) {
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            private Border outside      = new MatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.RED);
            private Border _outside     = new MatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.GREEN);
            private Border inside       = new EmptyBorder(0, 1, 0, 1);
            private Border highlight    = new CompoundBorder(outside, inside);
            private Border _highlight   = new CompoundBorder(_outside, inside);

            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                JComponent jc = (JComponent)c;
                String type = (String)getModel().getValueAt(convertRowIndexToModel(row), 1);

                if (isRowSelected(row)) {           
                    if ("test".equals(type)) {
                        jc.setBorder( _highlight ); // Green color
                        jc.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        jc.setBorder( highlight ); //Red color
                    }
                }

                return c;
            }
        };

        //table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        //table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);        
        return new JScrollPane( table );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Row Rendering");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableRowRenderingTip() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So needless to say I am a little frustrated to say the lest since I've been working on this for a few hours now trying to find out what could be the issue.

I'm sure it will be something simple that I'm looking over...

Comment: [tag:eclipse] tag removed as the question has nothing to do with Eclipse per se, and [tag:swing] added, as it has *everything* to do with Swing

Comment: Well you based your code from: [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which provided a working example. So how is your code different than the code in the working example? Go back to the original code and make one change at a time to make sure the code still works. Then when it stops working you know what the problem is.@HovercraftFullOfEels already pointed out one difference. I see another difference in your if statement. The working example uses a "!" in the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to set the border and highlighting back to default if the test condition is not true. For example

```
if (isRowSelected(row)) {
    if ("test".equals(type)) {
        jc.setBorder(_highlight); // Green color
        jc.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        jc.setBorder(highlight); // Red color
    }
} else {
    jc.setBorder(null);
    jc.setBackground(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hovercraft it no longer paints green in each row. However, when I click out of the cell when I type in **test** it does not paint that row green. Clicking on the test cell again shows the row as green. But once I click off of that it goes back to the original color which I do not want. I need it to stay there.

Comment: @StealthRT Hovercraft highlighted a shortcoming in your understanding of table cell renderers, the fact that the component returned from `super.prepareRenderer` is a rubber-stamp for rendering all cells in the table. Once you set a property on the component it will retain that property. That is because prepareRenderer will delegate to DefaultTableCellEditor (at least for your implementation). See [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) for some documentation.

Comment: @StealthRT What this boils down to: each time you prepare the renderer, you should set each and every significant property (color and border in your case).